# Loading just an attribute from a model and saving it

Tags: attributes, customer, resource-model

What is the most efficient way (using Magento methods) to load just a customer attribute, changing its value and saving it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have the customer model (at least partially loaded), you can use this line to save a single attribute:

```
$customer->getResource()->saveAttribute($customer, 'attribute_code_goes_here');
```

Actually, for this to work, the only attributes that must be present in the `$customer` instance are `entity_id` and the attribute that you want to save. You can load the customer with only selected EAV attributes like this:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->load($customerId, array('attribute_code_goes_here'));
```

Comment: apologies for taking so long to mark it as correct, was just reviewing my questions and saw this

Answer (score 1):

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail('customer@email.com');

//or if you know the customer ID
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id, array('attribute_code'));

// attribute_code
$customer->setAttributeCode('new value here')->save();
```

This will save only the value changed. Magento strips out all non changed elements and only saves what has been changed from the data.

It does this in: `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_collectSaveData()` which is a parent of `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer`, which handles saving functionality.